# Browser() equivalent function in Python

Tags: python

In `R`, `browser()` [function](http://rfunction.com/archives/2633) is used inside any user defined function. It freezes the function once it executes and then we can see the values assigned to function variables.
For example, when we call below-mentioned function, it will freeze at first step and then we will be able to check the values of `a` and `b`.

```
      do_addition <- function(a,b){
                browser() # it will freeze function here and we can check a, b values
                return(a+b)
                 }
```

Is there any such function in Python which allows looking into the values of variables inside a function?

Comment: `import pdb; pdb.set_trace()` - the python debugger (various graphical options also available).

Comment: Use Python Debugger `pdb`? Or just add a `print(locals())` for debugging.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using `pdb` can work for some quick inspection, but if you really want to debug the script, check out [PyCharm](https://www.jetbrains.com/pycharm/). They have a community edition that is pretty robust and fairly easy to set up.